# Why shell_exec returns different response than bash terminal?

Tags: bash, php

I'm running this code in php:

```
shell_exec("cat /proc/mounts | grep \"^/dev\" | grep -v loop");
```

and it returns

```
/dev/sda5 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0 /dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0 /dev/sda5 /tmp ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0 /dev/sda5 /var/tmp ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0 /dev/sdb1 /work/hd1 ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

But when I run it directly from terminal I got:

```
/dev/sda5 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

And my disk drive /dev/sdb1 isnt even mounted!!

I don't know whats going on!
I'm running ubuntu 20.04 with php 7.4 and apache2.

Comment: Notice that /dev/sdb1 *is* in the output; it's just been wrapped into one line -- look further to the right. I'm not good enough with php to tell you the best fix, but let's narrow down the problem. What are you trying to get from the php code: just the root filesystem device? All of the local filesystems? There may be more robust ways to approach this.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm trying to get all available devices on the system. This is the only way I know to do so, I need to get it from php because I'm building a web page where I can list , create and format a partition.

Comment: Then I'm going to recommend (in general, because I don't know enough PHP) that you find a way to bring the /proc/mounts file in as an array/list and parse it within PHP. Also note that grepping out "loop" could remove valid entries.

Comment: It can't be "_all available devices_" because you're excluding loop devices

Comment: since you'll be doing further parsing, why don't read `/proc/mounts` as a (read-oonly) file and parse it ?

Comment: @Archemar the problem isnt the parsing, the problem is if I run the cat command from php it outputs invalid data, as you can see up there in the post, sdb1 is beign returned but its not mounted, its like apache or php is creating some kind of cache idk.

Comment: You could try `lsblk`. Something like `lsblk --noheadings --output mountpoint|xargs`

Comment: when I try on my host, I have no return at all from php (and 3 FS when in command line) (php cli 7.4.3 built 25 Nov 2021)